# Can i get also column name using max() function?

Tags: laravel

i get max value for column but i want to get also the column name of that max value

```
$getdata = DB::table('item')->get();
$sum=array();
foreach($getdata as $abc)
$ab = max(
$abc->jan,
$abc->feb,
$abc->mar,
$abc->apr, 
$abc->may,
$abc->jun, 
$abc->jul,
$abc->aug,
$abc->sep, 
$abc->oct,
$abc->nov, 
$abc->dec);
$sum[] = $ab;
```

When i Run this code

```
[5,2,12,1]
```

Here is the table

[image]

Comment: not with that method, no .. also there is the potential that multiple columns have the same max value, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the key of the highest(s) element(s) with the following code:

```php
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array))
```

You may add the `$maxs` variable to the `$sum` array and return it as a multidimensional array.

Comment: using max on array gives max value of its index but this give me a good idea ty